# Python script can't find path

Tags: python

When I execute the following line in my script:

```
if os.path.exists('/home/jsc0606/Desktop/project/myfile.py')
```

I get `False`. However, when I execute the same line in the terminal in the same directory, I get `True`. Does anyone know why Python can't find the file when executing that line in the script?

Comment: Check the read/write permissions?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) about `os.path.exists`:

> On some platforms, this function may return `False` if *permission is not granted* to execute `os.stat()` on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.

I think this may be the case: you're probably running the script with different privileges.

Comment: How do I grant permission to execute os.stat()? sudo?

Comment: @Soubriquet, first you need to understand _to which user_ you want to grant the permissions and _what permissions exactly_ you should grant. Check under what user your script and your interpreter run. Try to run both under the same user (e.g. the user you're using to log in).

Comment: Is there any way to grant permissions regardless of what platform I'm on? Sorry I'm not very familiar with this stuff.

Comment: @Soubriquet, certainly no: Windows and *nix'es have different permissions mechanisms, for example. Anyway, you first need to know to which user to grant these permissions. If you're on Linux, you can do `sudo chmod 777 <your_file>` to make it possible for every user to do whatever the heck they want with the file (read, write & execute).

Comment: `sudo chmod 777` did not work on my script for finding that file

Comment: @Soubriquet, how exactly are you running the script and the interpreter (what are the exact commands?) and under what user?

Comment: I'm running both under the same user

Comment: script: `python retriever.py` interpreter: `python`, `import os`, `if os.path.exists('/home/jsc0606/Desktop/project/myfile.py')`

Comment: @Soubriquet, but `if os.path.exists(...)` is not valid syntax. If you do `if os.path.exists(...): print("FOUND IT")`, what does it output in the terminal and in the script?

Comment: The script outputs nothing and the terminal outputs `FOUND IT`

Comment: @Soubriquet, very odd. When you run a script, it's processed by the same Python interpreter, so if the script contains the same code you put into the interpreter, it should work in the same way... Okay, does using `os.path.isfile` instead of `os.path.exists` produce the same behavior?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, what is this link for?